# Cannot load CSS and JS dynamically with this function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load Plugins based on the condition as in the below function. But i am unable to do it. Please have a look at the code and let me know the errors in the code..

```
  function loadPlugin(choic)
  {
    var plugin=choic*1;
    if(plugin >= 1 && plugin <= 3)
    {
        $("head").append("<link>");
        css = $("head").children(":last");
        css.attr(
            {
                rel:  "stylesheet",
                type: "text/css",
                href: "/cloud-zoom/cloud-zoom.css"
            });
        alert('CSS Loaded');
        alert($("head").html());
        $.getScript('/cloud-zoom/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js', function() 
        {
            alert($("head").html());
            $('.cloud-zoom').CloudZoom();
            $('a.cloud-zoom').live('click',function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    }   
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: What error message or erroneous behaviour are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getScript` should work just fine. Your problem is probably with the CSS. There's still no browser-wide way of loading stylesheets in a clean way. Your `alert('CSS loaded')` will always
happen at the same time the CSS loads (if running on localhost) or before it loads (not localhost).

Also, you could load your CSS in a diferent way:

```
$("head").append(
    $("<link>", {
        rel:  "stylesheet",
        type: "text/css",
        href: "/cloud-zoom/cloud-zoom.css"
    })
);
```

Another way of achieving this is downloading CSS using a `$.get()` and then inserting it into
a `<style>` tag, but that's no very pretty..